# CLion - Carriage return? \r

Tags: c, special-characters, clion, carriage-return

I am using the CLion IDE and I am trying to do a carriage return.

I am doing a print statement in C and have the following syntax:

`printf("\rHello World!");` which is inside a loop. The loop still prints every `Hello World` on its own line. There are no `\n`'s in my program. I've tried changing the `line separators` options to `unix` `mac OS` and `windows` and none of them change the functionality. Google has also led me to no useful answers.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5000000)
    {
        printf("\rThis is line number %d!", i++);   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is only a single line of text in the console window.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1265.htm  Hope that helps

Comment: What OS are you running this on, as the behaviour of the \r may well depend upon the terminal it's appearing on.

Comment: unhelpful bug here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000221704-Clion-How-to-carriage-return-in-console-prints-

Comment: what if you write `printf("This is line number %d!\r", i++); fflush(stdout);`?

Comment: Just for grins, it might be interesting to write your output to a file or memory block and then inspect the result to see if perhaps an \n is being introduced unexpectedly by the compiler...or perhaps translating the \r into an \r\n combination...

Comment: It's completely possible that the cross-platform clion is "supporting" the oldschool apple users who have CR as newline character.

Comment: This might be printf; try `puts("\rfoobar");`.

Comment: For me, on WSL, `\r` causes the cursor to go to the start of the line without going to a new line (akin to pressing Home in Word) and overwrites the old line.

Comment: @Anona112; Which OS you are using?

Comment: Try compile with a latest C++ compiler and see. Your code is working fine for me while I have compiled with C++ compiler and out put is only one single line. Your current compiler is adding a '\n' character at the end of printf statement.

Comment: @haccks Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: What compiler are you using? `g++ --version`

Comment: Please execute your program from outside of CLion, i.e., from the shell. Do you get the same output?

Comment: already did fflush(stdout); g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5); same code behaves well in Terminal, so it must be a CLion thing.

Comment: works now after reboot without any changes. how can I award the 50 to Murphy or God?

Comment: now that's something: doesn't work when Debugging, works when Running!
Also printf("\r%d",i) acts as "\r\n" , printf("%d\r",i) ignores the "\r"

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is PuTTY console, that is used in CLion by default.
You can switch it off in Registry:

```
Help | Find Action | Registry... =>
run.processes.with.pty [ ] <- uncheck
```

I recommend you modify the program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 500) {
        printf("\rThis is line number %d!", i++);
        fflush(stdout); // <- add this call
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related issue in the tracker
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6949

Comment: I'll give this a try very soon. Thanks!

Comment: Problem reappeared. In Debug only!

Comment: You need set up the Registry for each CLion re-run. In the case of Debug, your program get the console from debugger and it is different story. It depends heavily on the debugger, OS and settings.