# Carriage return in CLion

Tags: c++, console, output, special-characters, clion

Here is a simple program designed to keep track of loop progress and print it at certain stages (every 10% in this example).

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double step = 0.1;
    double last_progress = 0;
    int num_iter = 100;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_iter; ++i) {
        double k = i * 1.0 / num_iter;
        if (k > last_progress + step) {
            last_progress += step;
            printf("\r%7.2f%%", last_progress * 100);
            fflush(stdout);
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to have a single overridable line showing the current progress. If I launch this program in a console everything works as expected. However, when I try to execute it in CLion (2017.1.1) I get the following output:

```
  10.00%  20.00%  30.00%  40.00%  50.00%  60.00%  70.00%  80.00%  90.00% 100.00%
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825574/clion-carriage-return-r) thread and I tried disabling putty but it didn't help. This problem has something to do with time in between prints for when I remove the sleep line everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally discovered that if you print double \r with some text in between then it starts working.

```
printf("\rAny text here\r%7.2f%%", last_progress * 100);
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing `\n` at the end of your printf argument

Comment: No, if I add \n then each line will be printed on a new line. I expect the output to have a _single overridable line_ showing the current progress. This problem exists in CLion only.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood your question. have you tried to use `\b` instead?

Comment: Just tried but it didn't help. It works fine in console, but CLion doesn't capture it correctly for some reason.